# python 2.7 access denined when writing a file to Windows

Tags: python, windows, boto3

I'm trying to use a python script to download a file from s3 to my Windows 10 laptop. I'm running the 
prompt "as administrator". I have given everyone full access to the folder I'm trying to write the file 
to, but windows is still giving an "access denied" error.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('kapps2.services-exchange.com').download_file('myconfig.py', 
'C:\data')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 168, in 
bucket_download_file
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 130, in 
download_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 307, in 
download_file
    future.result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 73, in 
result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 233, in 
result
    raise self._exception
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\data'
```

I'm new to Python, can anyone help with this? Thank You

Comment: I think it might be from not escaping the \ in the path on Windows.  Try 'C:\\data' or 'C:/data'

Comment: Definitely watch those backslashes in string literals to avoid problems with control characters such as "\n" and "\t". Use raw strings, or use forward slashes when allowed, or use forward slashes followed by `os.path.normpath`, or use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the boto3 documentation (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

The example is : 
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')

It is specifying the target filename (my_local_image.jpg) and not only the directory where to save the file. So your code should be :

```
s3.Bucket('kapps2.services-exchange.com').download_file('myconfig.py', 'C:/data/myconfig.py')
```

Comment: C has an `EISDIR` error, and the Windows kernel has `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`. But the Windows API layered in between these two has no error code for this case. Instead it maps `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` unhelpfully to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5), so people waste time assuming it's a permissions problem instead of a usage problem.